# There is no error but nothing is printed, but if I print inside the while loop then it is printed multiple times. How do I fix this?

Tags: python, printing, while-loop

```
data = open("t.txt","r")
list1 = []
while True:
    text = data.readline()
    count = {
        "a": [],
        "b": [],
        "c": [],
        "d": []
    }
    for item in count:
        if item in text or "Subject" in text:
            list1.append(text)
data.close()
print(list1)
```

Comment: ...Why are you creating a dictionary, then iterating only over the keys of it, and you never modify it... why not just `count = "abcd"`? Also, instead of using a `while True` + `readline()` you should just iterate over the file: `for text in data: for item in "abcd": ... `

Comment: As far as your actually question, I don't see how your loop exits. So, it never gets to the print.

Comment: Add `if not text: break` after the `data.readline()`.

Answer (score 3):

Your while loop appears to be the problem. It is "while True" -- since True will always equal True, your loop will continue to loop forever. If your print list1 is inside the loop, it prints each of those times. If it is out of the loop it will never be run.

I'd say you could add logic to the loop to break it, but I quite honestly don't see from this code why you have the outer loop at all. You should probably just do the FOR loop and move on with the code.

To confirm this, just put a "break" at the end of your loop to exit. Once confirmed, I'd remove the outer loop entirely unless there is a reason to have it that isn't visible in your post.

Answer (score 0):

Your loop is the problem, it loops forever!  You want to loop over the text in the file, something like:

```
for text in data:
    ...
```